# How can you make the jQuery scroll() function to fire a second function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

My attempt: https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/gRLeVY?editors=1010

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).scroll(function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$("#mainContainer").css("transform", "translateX(-100vw)");

})


})
```

This is driving me nuts. I'm trying to make my site scroll a full page horizontally. I figured the first part out but alas it stops working after the second scroll.

PS: from my pen you can see I have the body set to overflow hidden but have it commented out (my code only works if I don't have it set so).

Someone please help me figure this out.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to better describe the desired behaviour from the user's point of view? The code shown does respond to the scroll event by applying that CSS transform.

Comment: I'm sorry english is not my first language, I'm having trouble describing what I want to achieve, but basically I need to have my website first scroll 100vw horizontally on the first scroll, and on the next scroll another 100vw, do you have any recommendations on how I can rephrase my question?

PS I figured out a way to make the scroll work btw with the body set to overflow hidden, instead of scroll() I am now using on('mousewheel')

Answer (score 0):

In your CodePen, I only added `e` between the parenthesis  in 
`$(document).on('mousewheel', function(e){`

That is the event object passed to your function.
It is needed to compare the wheel delta.

You had it in the `$(document).ready(function(e){` where it was useless.

So here is your [**CodePen** updated](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/qjqyxx) just like this.

---

**Just for fun**... I customized it a little more by foreseeing what someone would like to change using this "div translation" effect.

The first thing is certainly the div amount.
And the translation "fraction" would be another thing...
And a minimum delay between each translation.

So here is a [**CodePen** taking this in account](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JJbBBL?editors=1011).

Comment: no wonder it stopped working, i removed it to test something out a while ago and didn't notice i put it back in the wrong place, also the only problem left now is how to get it so the subsequent scrolls do not fire unless the previous scrolls haven't finished animating yet, any ideas? and also maybe another approach that isn't "glitchy", i've noticed sometimes when i scroll after i've just reloaded the page the animations don't fire right away, there is a sort of "delay" i think...

Comment: To give you a clear idea of what I am trying to recreate please refer to this website: http://10x16.com/